# How call EndEvent in EventSubProcess in Camunda

Tags: bpmn, camunda

I have diagramm
[image]

When I call task3 in Event SubProcess and completed task my process instance is closed, but EndEvent does not call. Why? (((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) Are you sure you want to be using terminating end events everywhere?
https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/reference/bpmn20/events/terminate-event/
and
https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/reference/bpmn20/events/none-events/

Since there is no parallel activity, is see no need for a terminating end event. in general I discourage the use of terminating end events. There are usually better ways to achieve the desired outcome.

b) The event sub process uses an **interrupting** start event.
https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/reference/bpmn20/subprocesses/event-subprocess/

> An event subprocess may be interrupting or non-interrupting. An
> interrupting subprocess cancels any executions in the current scope. A
> non-interrupting event subprocess spawns a new concurrent execution.
> While an interrupting event subprocess can only be triggered once for
> each activation of the scope hosting it, a non-interrupting event
> subprocess can be triggered multiple times. Whether the subprocess is
> interrupting or non-interrupting is configured using the start event
> which triggers the event subprocess.

Your parent process' execution is canceled by the interrupting start event of the event sub process. Next, only the sub process is executed.

Comment: yes, I changed on 'none'. But, i don't understand why after task3 don't call EndEvent((( But after task2 End called

Comment: Thanks, it;s ok, I create new diagramm and included both processes to common SubProcess like here https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/reference/bpmn20/subprocesses/event-subprocess/

Answer (score 0):

My new diagramm. Now called EndEvent on both processes
[image]

Comment: Glad it works. I believe you also don't need the terminating end event on the alternative path.